# jquery validate plugin combine field validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

On one form I have City, State, ZIP code on one line in the form (inside one block element).

My error div for the validate plugin slides nicely under the form div so that message is contextual.

Is there a way to combine a rule so that it's not 3 separate validation rules?  In other words, if city is blank, or state is blank, or ZIP is blank, I want to trigger just one error message div "City, State and ZIP code are required".  Likewise if 2 of 3 or 3 of 3 are blank I still want to have just one error div returned by validate.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `groups` and `errorPlacement` option to your needs.
For example (taken from http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate):

```
$("#myform").validate({
  groups: {
    username: "fname lname"
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     if (element.attr("name") == "fname" 
                 || element.attr("name") == "lname" )
       error.insertAfter("#lastname");
     else
       error.insertAfter(element);
   },
   debug:true
 });
```